# Why can't I edit my .xlsx file with openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am encountering a problem when running with openpyxl the code below

```
import openpyxl
import os

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet["A1"].value
sheet["A1"].value == None
sheet["A1"].value = 42
sheet["A3"].value = 'Hello'
os.chdir("/Users/mac/Desktop")
wb.save('exceeeel.xlsx')
```

The error is

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 312, in load_wo
rkbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 124, in __init_
_
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 96, in _validat
e_archive
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using the current version of the openpyxl library.

Comment: This is only a part of of the error message. Please post _the full traceback_.

Comment: It seems like only the first line of the code is relevant. Did you include all of the error message? I

Comment: Please check your code now that it is readable.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Also, what is your question? Stack Overflow is not a free debugging service.

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a confident answer because the question only includes a partial traceback.  That being said, it looks like the traceback one would get for a `FileNotFoundError`:

```sh
C:\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/scratch/scratch2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/scratch/scratch2.py", line 3, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 313, in load_workbook
    data_only, keep_links)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1207, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'example.xlsx'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This error will be raised when the path your provided to the file you want to load with `openpyxl.load_workbook` does not contain the specified file. Since the only argument you provided in your call of that function is `'example.xlsx'` that probably means there is no file in the folder you are running this script from.

If this `'example.xlsx'` file is in a different folder then you'll want to either specify the relative path to that file as your argument or move the file into the same folder as your script.

If this isn't what's going on then you'll need to provide the full traceback that you are seeing on your end in order to get a better answer.